# How to use node-modules in client side

Tags: node.js, npm, requirejs

I am trying to use node-module MSSQL with a one page html. I don't want to use nodejs for some reasons. I did my research where I can use static files for the node-modules. I tried with requirejs but it does not work. Below are my code. Or I am having a wrong understanding of what RequireJS is for.

db.js

```
requirejs.config({

});

requirejs(["scripts/r.js-master/dist.js"], function(rjs) {
    rjs.config({
        nodeRequire: require, mysql
    });
    console.log("test");
    var sql = require("mssql");
    var config = {
        user: '',
        password: '',
        server: '', 
        database: '',
        options: {
            encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
        }
    }



    sql.connect(config, function(err) {
        // ... error checks
        // Query
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select 1 as number', function(err, recordset) {
            // ... error checks
            console.dir(recordset);
        });

    });
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script data-main="scripts/db" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

The error is :

```
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Comment: Since you can't make client-side file requests like that, you'll need something like Browserify or Webpack, and it will compile those modules into your actual code

Comment: Asking which wrapper you should use makes your question a recommendation question, and we close these. Turning it into a "how can I get the MSSQL package to work in the browser" is too broad, and we close such questions. The answer to the issue of getting a module designed for Node to work in the browser is addressed by part 3 of the answer to the question against which I closed yours. You need to pick a method and then when you run into a *specific* problem you may have a good question to ask on SO.